# Creating a trigger to insert records from a table to another one. Triggered column of table 'A' is inserted as null in table 'B'

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have two tables `tbl_PurchaseDetails` and `tbl_ItemDetails`. I need to insert some records into `tbl_ItemDetails` from `tbl_PurchaseDetails`, right after it is inserted in `tbl_PurchaseDetails`. `tbl_PurchaseDetails` has auto generated custom field `PurchaseID`.

**Code for auto generation of `PurchaseID` is:-**
**This trigger works perfectly**

```
CREATE FUNCTION CreatePurchaseID (@id INT) 
RETURNSvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 'P' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @id)
END

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_PurchaseID ON tbl_PurchaseDetails 
FOR INSERT AS
UPDATE
    tbl_PurchaseDetails 
SET
    tbl_PurchaseDetails.PurchaseID = dbo.CreatePurchaseID(tbl_PurchaseDetails.ID) 
FROM
    tbl_PurchaseDetails 
INNER JOIN 
INSERTED on tbl_PurchaseDetails.ID= INSERTED.ID
```

**I have written the following code for trigger to insert into `tbl_ItemDetails`:-**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_UpdateItemDetails ON tbl_PurchaseDetails
FOR INSERT AS
DECLARE @PurchaseID VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @Quantity INT
DECLARE @WarehouseID VARCHAR(20)

SELECT @PurchaseID=(PurchaseID) FROM INSERTED
SELECT @Quantity=(ItemQuantity) FROM INSERTED
SELECT @WarehouseID=(WarehouseID) FROM INSERTED

INSERT INTO 
tbl_ItemDetails
(PurchaseID,Quantity,WarehouseID)
VALUES
(
@PurchaseID,@Quantity,@WarehouseID
)
```

**And now when i insert into `tbl_PurchaseDetails` the records are added to `tbl_PurchaseDetails` and `tbl_ItemDetails` successfully. The problem here is, the `PurchaseID` is inserted as null in `tbl_ItemDetails`. It is inserted as expected in `tbl_PurchaseDetails` though.

Comment: Why not just make `PurchaseID` a computed column (using the function you already have, or just inline) and remove the first trigger entirely?

Comment: Also, your second trigger is fundamentally broken - it assumes only a single row in `INSERTED`

Comment: I did try to do so but i ran into problems. It would be great if you help me with some code to do so. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: And about the second trigger that is what i want it to work like. :)

Comment: Re: second trigger, no , you really don't. There's no guarantee that the 3 selects that set your variables will select columns from the *same* row of `inserted`. You could end up with PurchaseID, ItemQuantity and WarehouseID from 3 different rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comments, here's what I'd have:

```
CREATE TABLE PurchaseDetails ( --Why have a tbl_ prefix on every table?
     ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
     PurchaseID as 'P' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ID),
     --Other columns
)
```

I then wouldn't need your first trigger and function. I could then re-write the second trigger as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_UpdateItemDetails ON PurchaseDetails
FOR INSERT AS
   INSERT INTO ItemDetails(PurchaseID,Quantity,WarehouseID)
   SELECT PurchaseID,ItemQuantity,WarehouseID
   FROM inserted
```

which deals with `inserted` potentially containing multiple rows.

---

Re: my comment in the first snippet about `tbl_` prefixes - I'd argue that it's not just adding redundant information, it's adding potential for confusion. The only two types of objects that can appear, ambiguously, in the same position within a query are tables and views. Any other type of object (function, stored procedure, column, parameter, etc) can always be distinguished by syntax at the point of usage.

And, as much as possible, you shouldn't *want* or *need* to distinguish between tables and views. Being able to completely change a table, but then provide a view that has the same layout as the original table, and the same name, and then not having to change any other code is a great virtue in SQL. But it feels kind of silly when you have to name your view `tbl_ABC` because you were using `tbl_` as a prefix for tables.

Comment: on the prefix issue: on the other hand, you can't (usually) insert or update views, and their performance characteristics can be sufficiently different that in some cases it's worth highlighting that your query isn't as trivial as it looks.  I still don't think it's worth such the prefix, but sometimes you do want and need to distinguish tables and views.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne - I can be a bit of a relational snob at times :-)